# Pass DateTime from View to Controller in UK format in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my View:

```
@Html.TextBox("fromDateFilter")
```

However, when I input 01/02/2015, my controller seems to receive it as 02/01/2015. I can tell this from debugging. My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? fromDateFilter = null)
{
    etc...
}
```

I have tried to fix this by editing the web.config file, by adding this line under system.web:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

I have also tried changing the TextBox to this:

```
@Html.TextBox("fromDateFilter", "" , "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Neither of these options worked and I am still confused as to what to do.

As I side note, I am in the UK and the database uses a format of yyyy-MM-dddd e.g.

```
2015-11-17 09:53:46.643
```

Comment: why doesn't your database store it as a datetime type not a string?

Comment: It is a datetime in the database. Why do you assume it is a string?

Comment: you are saying it uses a format, datetimes have no format.

Comment: I reproduce your issue, but in my case everything bind correctly. Check your `Web.Config` for other cases also you testing this on your local machine or on server? Could it be IIS config issue?

Comment: I am doing this on my local machine. Any idea what I can do to check the IIS config that could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack my answer, but it does resolve the problem. I chose to pass the date as a string (so it couldn't choose US date instead of UK) and converted it to a DateTime.

```
public ActionResult Index(string fromDateFilter = "")
{
    if (fromDate != "")
    {
        DateTime fromDateAsDateTime = DateTime.Parse(fromDateFilter);
        Does stuff here...
    }
}
```

Since I am forcing selection to be in the UK format using a jQuery datepicker function, and displaying all dates in UK format, this method does works. However, this would not work if needed this project in both the USA and the UK...

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me.  I have also upvoted the question.  +1.